# Retrieving parameters from a JQuery Ajax call when calling a JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to utilise JQuery Ajax to call a javascript file. I need to pass it some parameters but I am not certain how to when using javascript (PHP seems simpler). Here is my call:

```
function getDocument(parameters) {
    $.ajax({
        type:       "GET",
        url:        "js/document.js",
        dataType:   "script",
        data:       "info=hellothere",
        success:    function(msg) { 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        }
    });
}
```

All I would like to do, is print out the contents of the parameter 'info' in document.js

So essentially is should print 'hellothere'.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using PHP.

Change the URL to `document.php`, and within that file do the following:

```
echo $_GET['info'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "js/document.js"
```

Should be the `path to the Server file`

You cannot send ajax request to your **.js** file using Ajax request

Send the request to the .php file and write up your method in there to process the data.

Ajax Request is primarily used to send data to and forth from the **Client side** to **server side** ..

If you want to access the data between two .js files better store that data in a `cookie` or a `local storage`